# Static UITableView not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

In my storyboard, I designed a tableview with static cells shown below:
[image]

But all I end up with is this:

[image]

Not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE`. Have you linked you `IBOutlet` with the `UITableView` in storyboards?

Comment: yes i've linked it to an IBOutlet, doesn't work

Comment: Well that is the sort of information that we need to know in the question. Showing two screen shots and saying what is happening is for vague. Please update your question with relevant code, which clearly there is some.

Comment: For use UITableView in view you have to set outlet of UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate and also you have to write UITableview delegate methods in your .m file

Comment: i did this...doesn't work. This is my code: -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] init];
    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}

Answer (score 1):

Drag and Drop `UITableViewController` from object library and embed in `UINavigationController`
Design your UI and run - it works for me.

**Remember** - You can't drag and drop UIViewController and on top of UITableView.

Comment: is there any way to do it with view controller

Comment: @Allen - Perhaps there is no other way as per my knowledge -

Answer (score 0):

Set `IBOutlet` for `UITableView` in your **viewcontroller.h** file. Try this. Hope it will works fine.